# unable to send email in my php form

Tags: php, smtp, email

I am Unable to send mails. i would like to know what i am doing wrong or how to connect to smtp.

Here is my code which i am using for sending emails.

Am i missing something

```
$to='pratik.purohit@steeplap.com';
$subject='Hey';
$body='
This is a test email
';
$headers='From: pratik.purohit@steeplap.com';
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
echo 'mail send '.$to;
}
else{
echo "mail not send";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `@` before `mail ()` to see what's wrong in logs.

If you want to send emails using an external smtp server then use PHPMailler library.

Comment: and if want to do it on the same server?

Comment: Just check if you have already a mail server installed, else you can look for some tutorial that explain how to install a mail server.